# Get value from json value key pair with D3

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I'm using D3 to draw lines from a json array. I can get the values from it for the x and y coordinates, but I'm trying to get a line name and assign it to the path object id but getting all sort of [object object} errors.
The array I'm using is:
   [ {name: "line1", x: 1, y: 1},{name: "line1", x: 1, y: 2},{name: "line1", x: 1, y: 5},]

It's the same for the different lines and the name is repeated as I may need it in each data point.

The code is:

```
var width = 500,
        height = 500,
        margin = 50,
        x = d3.scale.linear()
                .domain([0, 10])
                .range([margin, width - margin]),
        y = d3.scale.linear()
                .domain([0, 10])
                .range([height - margin, margin]);


var actionsD3 = [
[ {name: "line1", x: 1, y: 1},{name: "line1", x: 2, y: 2},{name: "line1", x: 3, y: 5},]
];

var line = d3.svg.line()
        .x(function(d){return x(d.page);})
        .y(function(d){return y(d.characterid);});

var lineName = d3.select()
        .jsonData(function(d){return (d.name);});

svg.attr("height", height)
        .attr("width", width);

function render(data) {
        svg.selectAll("path")
                        .data(data)
                .enter()
                        .append("path")
                        .attr("class", "line")
                        .attr("id",function(d){return lineName(d);})
                        .attr("d", function(d){return line(d);});
}

render(actionsD3);
```

What I'd like is the same as for the line where I get the value for x and y with d.x and d.y.
But I seem to always get the pair or an array.

Thanks

Comment: The code you've posted doesn't work, but from your description it would be something like `.attr("id", function(d) { return d[0].name; })`.

Comment: Awesome Lars, working perfectly :-)

Comment: Great, I'll add this as an answer for reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you've posted doesn't work, but from your description it would be something like `.attr("id", function(d) { return d[0].name; })`. The idea is that you're passing in an array that designates the line and get the ID from the first point of the line.